# What are Dangling Images in Docker/How they created/How to remove them

Tags: docker, dockerfile

How do dangling images get created? Whenever I tried to create them it is not happening.

I had used the same concept as mentioned in docker docs. If my DockerFile contains `FROM alphine:3.4` then I build the image as `docker build -t image1 .`

After some time I update it as `FROM alphine:3.5` and again building it as `docker build -t image1 .`

But it is showing me three images no dangling one??

[image]

Comment: Now update the dockerfile ...

Comment: "dangling image" is the images which are untagged and you can see <none> as the name of them, remove them using `docker image prune` and list them `docker images -f dangling=true`

Comment: Why do you want to create a dangling image?

Comment: I want to create a dangling image in order to understand the concept as when i dont know how they are created then what the purpose of understanding any topic..

Comment: I know what are dangling ones the <none> but how they are created??

Comment: Did you get a proper answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *really* want to create a dangling image, simply interrupt the build process before it's finished.

Honestly don't understand why you want to though; they are a by-product of a failed build, that's all.

Comment: Ok siha I actually want to understand the concept of  dangling images in docker how they created that's it there is not anything I am doing .  Thanks for your answer I will perform it by interrupt the build process

Answer (score 1):

> What are Dangling Images in Docker?

Dangling Images are temporary images that are created at the time of building the images in docker server. Since images are build on layers of commits.

> How they created?

There are created automatically. You can see them using `docker images -f dangling=true`

> How to remove them?

You can do system purge to remove danggling images like this `docker images purge`.

Comment: They are created automatically but there might some concept they are using ?/?? In my example i am using  build /tag the image in dockerfile and then update the dockerfile then i again build it using the same tag but it is not create a dangling image...

Comment: all of them are created at the time of building which are not required any more. Like no container is will use those images which container creation

Comment: You can see dangling images without the `-f dangling=true`. All that does is filter the output to *only* show those.

Comment: @Prisar Of course they are not required the <none> ones but i am asking how they are created??

Comment: dangling images are no longer connected to any conatiner. docker doesnt remove those container.

Comment: @Kairabansal they are  created at the time of building your required  image from a set of layers

Comment: @SiHa  i had use the  -f dangling=true but it is not showing as dangling ones are not created

Comment: Did you get proper answer?